# Using lapply to create new variables based on multiple conditions and subsets

Tags: r, list, apply, lapply

I am trying to create a list of new variables that represent the deviations from the minimum values of variables based on subsets of another variable.

Consider the following:

```
df <- data.frame(
      cluster = c("A","B","B","A","A","B"),
      x = c(3,4,1,5,2,6),
      y = c(4,5,3,1,2,6))
```

I would like to create two new variables, call them x.var and y.var, that take on the deviation from the minimum value of the respective underlying variables contingent on cluster. Thus, x.var and y.var would hopefully be:

```
x.var y.var
-1    -3
-3    -2
 0     0
-3     0
 0    -1
-5    -3
```

I have tried unsuccessfully to use lapply with an anonymous function to accomplish this:

```
vars <- lapply(df[,c(2:3)],function(x) 
    ifelse(df$cluster=="A",
    min(df[df$cluster=="A",x])-x,
    min(df[df$cluster=="B",x])-x))
```

I receive the following error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(df, df$cluster == "A", x) : undefined columns selected
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I think the 4th value of `x.var` should be `-3` (2-5) ?

Comment: You are right. Thanks for catching that. I adjusted the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `base R` method that uses `ave` with `lapply`. Loop through the columns of dataset excluding the 'cluster', then with `ave` get the `min` grouped by 'cluster', subtract from the column and assign the `list` of `vector`s to new columns

```
df[paste0(names(df)[-1], ".var")] <- lapply(df[-1], function(x)
                                         ave(x, df$cluster, FUN = min) - x)
df
#  cluster x y x.var y.var
#1       A 3 4    -1    -3
#2       B 4 5    -3    -2
#3       B 1 3     0     0
#4       A 5 1    -3     0
#5       A 2 2     0    -1
#6       B 6 6    -5    -3
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the recommended approach. This is extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using `dplyr`.

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  cluster = c("A","B","B","A","A","B"),
  x = c(3,4,1,5,2,6),
  y = c(4,5,3,1,2,6))

df %>% 
  group_by(cluster) %>% 
  mutate(x.var = min(x) - x,
         y.var = min(y) - y)

#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#> # Groups:   cluster [2]
#>   cluster     x     y x.var y.var
#>   <fct>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 A           3     4    -1    -3
#> 2 B           4     5    -3    -2
#> 3 B           1     3     0     0
#> 4 A           5     1    -3     0
#> 5 A           2     2     0    -1
#> 6 B           6     6    -5    -3
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi Jake. Thanks a ton for the recommendation. This approach completely solves my inquiry.